# Error when running BibTex for beamer document

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibtex

When running `BibTex` in a `beamer` document terminal returns:

`Error : could not start the command : bibtex"powerP".aux`

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usecolortheme{whale} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}
\usepackage{csquotes} %"para citar bien"
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{hall2012glioxal,
  Title                    = {Activation of benznidazole by trypanosomal type I nitroreductases results in glyoxal formation},
  Author                   = {Hall, Belinda S and Wilkinson, Shane R},
  Year                     = {2012},
  Number                   = {1},
  Pages                    = {115--123},
  Volume                   = {56},

  Journal                  = {Antimicrobial agents and chemotherapy},
  Publisher                = {Am Soc Microbiol}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

\end{document}
```

When typing `bibtex poweP.aux` on terminal, it returns:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017)
The top-level auxiliary file: poweP.aux
The style file: biblatex.bst
Database file #1: poweP-blx.bib
Database file #2: poweP.bib
Biblatex version: 3.3
```

Any help please?

Comment: Is there really no space after `bibtex`?

Comment: that's a copy of the `.tex` file..@UlrikeFischer

Comment: No I mean above in the error message.

Comment: Which editor are you using? How is bibtex configured there?

Comment: @samcarter TexMaker and it is configured as: `Bib(la)tex : bibtex%.aux`

Comment: @HernanMiraola There is a space missing: `bibtex %.aux`

Comment: @samcarter same error now with a space: `Error : could not start the command : bibtex "powerP".aux` . the post was edited with more information..

Comment: There should be no quotation marks around `powerP`. Do you really have `bibtex %.aux` and no `"`s in the setting?

Comment: Note that with TeX live 2017 you should switch to Biber. Use `backend=biber` and have a look at [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: @moewe In `documentclass report` I haven't had problems with bibliography, and am using bibtex. I have tried also changing bibtex to biber but same error. Anyway, I will read the post. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: If you change to `backend=biber` you must also change your editor settings to make it call Biber. Instead of `Bib(la)tex : bibtex %.aux` you will then need `Bib(la)tex : biber %` (note: no `.aux`) as explained in the link.

Comment: @moewe oh, I didn't know about removing `.aux`. And then rerun with bibtex-->pdfLatex..cycle?

Comment: It worked! thanks @moewe. If you want answer the post. Just saying that about texLive 2017 and modification of texmaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take the opportunity and switch from BibTeX to Biber. Since you are using TeX live 2017 this should work more or less out of the box.

Simply change `backend=bibtex` to

```
backend=biber
```

and tell your editor to run Biber for you ([Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)). With Texmaker that comes down to

```
Bib(la)tex: biber %
```

in the 'commands' settings.

Comment: I was confused, it returns some strange thinh now: `! Use of \sortlist doesn't match its definition.` Any idea?

Comment: @HernanMiraola Delete the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and recompile from scratch.

Comment: It got the same error.. :(

Comment: @HernanMiraola What does `biber --version` output in the command line? What version does `biblatex` report in the `.log` file if you add `\listfiles` to the start of your document?

Comment: This is the output when run bibtex: `This is Biber 1.9 INFO - Logfile is 'poweP.blg' INFO - Reading 'poweP.bcf' WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 3.3, expected version 2.6 INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0 INFO - ` but at the end it say: process exited normally. From command line it returns: version 2.7

Comment: Hmm not sure about how to look the version but in the log file I found: `Package: biblatex 2016/12/05 v3.7 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)`

Comment: @HernanMiraola That is confusing. Your BibTeX reports that you are running TeX live 2017 and your `biblatex` is really new as well. Your Biber, however, is really old. Did you have an older TeX live installed? Did you install Biber manually? What does `where biber` (Windows)/`which biber` (Unix) say?

Comment: You are correct. No, I have installed Biber from console, because I am not sure how install the current version manually. I have linux debian based, 64 bits.

Comment: @HernanMiraola You should not install Biber manually. It should already ship with TeX live. Remove all manually installed versions of Biber and try again. What does `where biber`/`which biber` say?

Comment: It says: `/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/biber`. Do you mean remove simply with `sudo apt-get remove biber`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66900/discussion-between-moewe-and-hernan-miraola).