# Empty bibliography - biber Texlive 2017

Tags: biber

When running pdfLatex -using biber- in TexMaker, terminal returns `empty bibliography`. Today someone [helps me to solve it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395478/error-when-running-bibtex-for-beamer-document) with beamer, but now somethings seems wrong with the `report document`.
Just for completeness, the way I am doing the compilation is BibTex-->pdfLatex-->BibTex-->pdfLatex. Below there is a MWE and after it an image of Texmaker configuration.
Also when running bibtex terminal returns

```
    INFO - This is Biber 2.7 INFO - Logfile is 'prueba.blg' INFO - Reading 
'prueba.bcf' INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0 WARN - The file 
'prueba.bcf' does not contain any citations! INFO - Writing 'prueba.bbl' 
with encoding 'UTF-8' INFO - Output to prueba.bbl INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```

for some reason `.bcf` file is not being produced also.

I have seen other posts but am not sure that this is the same problem. Any help will be welcome.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}  
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{csquotes} %"para citar bien"
%\usepackage[numbers, super]{natbib} %problems if uncomment
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{hall2012glioxal,
  Title                    = {Activation of benznidazole by trypanosomal type I nitroreductases results in glyoxal formation},
  Author                   = {Hall, Belinda S and Wilkinson, Shane R},
  Year                     = {2012},
  Number                   = {1},
  Pages                    = {115--123},
  Volume                   = {56},

  Journal                  = {Antimicrobial agents and chemotherapy},
  Publisher                = {Am Soc Microbiol}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%\addbibresource{bibtex.bib}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: texmaker]

Comment: Your configuration seems fine, biber was called. But you have no \cite command in your document.

Comment: Yes I know, but there is  `\printbibliography`, doesn't that mean to print it at the end of the document? @UlrikeFischer

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you are right. Short extra question: Is it possible to use something like `\usepackage[numbers, super]{natbib}` as I had on bibtex?

Comment: You get such things with biblatex styles (numeric) and the cite style (see supercite in the docu).

Comment: The line Bib(la)tex in the configuration image means that that program is called you wrote here down.  The usual way to compile is pdflatex -- bibtex -- pdflatex -- pdflatex.  In your case the compiling chain is: pdflatex -- biber -- pdflatex -- pdflatex. To be clear which tool for the bibliography is used wrote the name of the used engine. Then you omit missunderstandings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the following MWE. You missed to cite at last one or more bib entrys in your code.  After adding

```
Add \nocite{*} to call all bib entrys or cite at last one like~\cite{hall2012glioxal}!
%   ^^^^^^^^^^                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

you get the following compiling MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{hall2012glioxal,
  Title                    = {Activation of benznidazole by trypanosomal type I nitroreductases results in glyoxal formation},
  Author                   = {Hall, Belinda S and Wilkinson, Shane R},
  Year                     = {2012},
  Number                   = {1},
  Pages                    = {115--123},
  Volume                   = {56},

  Journal                  = {Antimicrobial agents and chemotherapy},
  Publisher                = {Am Soc Microbiol}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}  
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{csquotes} %"para citar bien"
%\usepackage[numbers, super]{natbib} %problems if uncomment

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

Add \nocite{*} to call all bib entrys or cite at last one like~\cite{hall2012glioxal}!
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

With option `backend=biber` for `biblatex` you need `biber` to build the bibliography ...

The resulting bibliography is then:

[image: resulting bibliography]

If you want to use `natbib` with `biblatex`, just use option `natbib` for `biblatex` like:

```
\usepackage[%
  style=verbose,
  backend=biber,
  natbib
]{biblatex}
```

To use the numeric style change the call of `biblatex` to:

```
\usepackage[%
% style=verbose,
  style=numeric,
  backend=biber,
  natbib=true
]{biblatex}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting bib]

To use the superscript I have to look into the documentation, I never used superscript here ...

Comment: Is it possible to remove the citation of the document if they are on `biber.bib` file? When tried that it doesn't find the refereces

Comment: @HernanMiraola Just comment out `\cite{hall2012glioxal}` in my MWE and compile three times. I guess the usage of `\nocite{*}` is what you are searching for ...

Comment: No, i mean to avoid having all citations inside the main file..; I have almost 50. I have learned how to do that with bibtex but no idea with biber

Comment: @HernanMiraola `\nocite{*}` called in your document does the following: All `*` bib entrys not cited are used to build the bibliography without leaving a citing in the document!  If you only want several bib entrys you can use the command `\nocite{key}` for each key you want to be in the bibliography.